# HTML5 php contact form script confirmation

Tags: php, javascript, forms, html, confirmation

I'm having some trouble with a script confirmation. By standard it's set to hide the contact form and display a confirmation message but it's not working for all browsers. After some tests I realized it doesn't work for most IE versions, which are around 40% of my visitors.

How do I replace the hide-and-show-msg to a "thankyou.html"? I'm guessing this works as most IEs fail to show the confirmation message although they manage to hide the form. The code in 'header' is currently:

```
<script src="php/js/jquery.validate.js"></script>
<script src="php/js/jquery.placeholder.js"></script>
<script src="php/js/jquery.form.js"></script>
<script>
$(function(){
$('#contact').validate({
submitHandler: function(form) {
    $(form).ajaxSubmit({
    url: 'thankyou.php',
    success: function() {
    $('#contact').hide();
    $('#contact-form').append("<p class='thanks'>Thank you! The message was sent.</center></p>")
    }
    });
    }
});         
});
</script>
```

Comment: I have solved it so far. Will investigate if I can fix it with your tags. Can you possibly post the complete page with CSS too?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved.

Reading http://groups.google.com/group/jquery-en/browse_thread/thread/58a9cbc1068d28c0/eb4bedb2cc36b126?pli=1

I added a conditional script

```
<head>
<!--[if IE]>
<script >
document.createElement("section"); 
</script >
<![endif]-->
```

http://plungjan.name/test/testform_validation.html

What you need to do is to append to an element understood by IE.

If you do not want the conditional script, add a div to the end of the page and append to that instead like here:  http://plungjan.name/test/testformvalidation.html

---

**Other issue**: I got

```
Webpage error details

User Agent: Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 8.0; Windows NT 5.1; Trident/4.0; .NET CLR 1.0.3705; .NET CLR 1.1.4322; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.0.04506.30; .NET CLR 3.0.4506.2152; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; InfoPath.1)
Timestamp: Tue, 17 May 2011 13:15:29 UTC


Message: Unexpected call to method or property access.
Line: 5569
Char: 5
Code: 0
URI: http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.6.1.js
```

Seems the finally is not supported

When I Added `catch(e) {}` before the finally - error gone

```
resolveWith: function( context, args ) {
  if ( !cancelled && !fired && !firing ) {
    // make sure args are available (#8421)
    args = args || [];
    firing = 1;
    try {
      while( callbacks[ 0 ] ) {
        callbacks.shift().apply( context, args );
      }
    }
    catch(e) { /* ADDED BY ME */ }
    finally {
      fired = [ context, args ];
      firing = 0;
    }
  }
  return this;
},
```

Comment: See my answer, I think I know why it won't show, because there's a closing center tag in the code, and the object should have been closed already, and IE cannot find another center object to close and thus errors out.

Comment: That is possible. but additionally, IE has a reputation of not wanting things to be appended to a form, instead wrap the form around a container like a DIV and append to that instead

Comment: <article class="page-content grid_8">
            <section id="contact-form">
                <h2 class="ribbon-404">Talk to us!</h2>
                <form id="contact" method="post" action="">
                    <p>
-standard form stuff
                    </p>
                </form>
            </section>
        </article>

Comment: I see no center tag in there. Thus that closing center tag in the append statement is not needed, and shouldn't be there.

Comment: The original code has the thankyou message in between center tags. I was removing stuff to post a smaller code here and missed that.

Comment: I'm getting 'settings' is null or not an object from line 21 of jquery.validate.min.js

Comment: It's something that was made for IE browsers. I get an error if it's not there and many if it is. I'm not sure why it's being asked but the official site is css3pie.com

Comment: That is a new question. I solved your initial question. It works now. If you want more help, please post a URL. You did not mention pie.js before

Comment: I don't have any links to a "PIE.js". It's just something IE asks when I try your code.

Comment: My bad I've just found some conditionals to each version of IE. They're probably conflicting with your code and asking for the PIE.

Comment: Thank you I'll keep on trying.

Answer (score 0):

Replace

```
$('#contact').hide();     $('#contact-form').append("<p class='thanks'>Thank you! The message was sent.</center></p>")
```

with `window.location.href="thankyou.html";`

Easy solution. Of course, this code uses relative paths, replace the "thankyou.html" with the actual location of that page.

Also, take out the part that says `</center>`. You shouldn't be adding a closing tag in that code, the center object should be closed correctly already. Perhaps that's the problem why IE won't show it. HTML coded wrong.

EDIT: And yes, if you so incline, you can use jQuery via `$(window.location).attr('href', 'thankyou.html');`
though this offers no benefits to my original solution, which is easier to read and understand, not to mention abitrarily faster.

Comment: Do you have the thankyou.html on the same path on the server? Error 405 indicates problems with the HTTP cycle, is it working for any other browser? Might be server issue.

Comment: I tested and got an error on $(location).attr. Seems there is no setAttribute on the location object

Comment: I used window.location in the above code, but in reality, window.location.href="thankyou.html" would work just fine.

Answer (score 0):

Set thankyou.php as the form action, and use jQuery validate() only to ensure that the form fields were completed:

```
<script>
    $(function(){
       $('#contact').validate({
            // Validate your form fields here
       });
    });
</script>
...
<form id="contact" action="thankyou.php" method="post">
```

Use thankyou.php to process the form submission and redirect the user to the thankyou.html:

```
<?php
header("Location: thankyou.html");
?>
```

This approach will eliminate the need for the AJAX call and form hiding.

Comment: Yes, good solution, or even better, have that PHP file output HTML, and thus even eliminate the need for the thankyou.html.